# Using "replace value of" to Perform a Partial Replace

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<Configuration>
    <Formula>{X} * {Y} * {Z}</Formula>
</Configuration>
```

I would like to *update* the value of the `Formula` element but not *replace* the entire value.

For example, I can use the `replace value of` method to change the entire value of the element but what I would like to end up with is something like the following:

```
<Configuration>
    <Formula>{LENGTH} * {Y} * {Z}</Formula>
</Configuration>
```

Of course, I would only like to have this done where I find the value "{X}" in the element value (think, search and replace).

Is this possible using the XML methods in T-SQL?  If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: are you set on XML methods? I'm not sure why `select replace('<Formula>{X} * {Y} * {Z}</Formula>','<Formula>{X}','<Formula>{LENGTH}')` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: The column in the table is of type XML.  I tried your suggestion and can get it to work but I have to cast the XML column as the first parameter to the REPLACE function.  I am not sure I want to do this (read, I am not sure if it is efficient).

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15 points border yourself you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

This code will transform your XML in a derived table and re-create an XML from there...

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Configuration>
    <Formula>{X} * {Y} * {Z}</Formula>
    <Formula>{A} * {Y} * {Z}</Formula>
    <Formula>{A} * {X} * {X}</Formula>
</Configuration>';

DECLARE @replX NVARCHAR(100)=N'LENGTH';

WITH AllFormulas AS
(
    SELECT f.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Formula 
    FROM @xml.nodes('Configuration/Formula') AS A(f)
)
SELECT REPLACE(Formula,N'X',@replX)
FROM AllFormulas
FOR XML PATH('Formula'),ROOT('Configuration')
```

The result

```
<Configuration>
  <Formula>{LENGTH} * {Y} * {Z}</Formula>
  <Formula>{A} * {Y} * {Z}</Formula>
  <Formula>{A} * {LENGTH} * {LENGTH}</Formula>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: In case there is something like {YX} in the formula, we could write SELECT REPLACE(Formula,N'{X}',N'{Length}')